# setting up JDBCTemplate in Spring using java configuration file

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I read in Spring in Action that a good way to set up JDBCTemplate is adding this in the Spring config file:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/AOICMainDB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
<bean id="jdbcTemplateDB2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource" />
</bean>
```

it makes sense, now we can autowire jdbcTemplateDB2 in a DAO and do jdbcTemplate stuff with it.

but how would I set this up using a java config file?  Specifically I'm not sure how the jee: namespace translates over to java confg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jee:jndi-lookup is just syntactical sugar for the JndiObjectFactoryBean.

The spring documentation provides a before and after example like so:

Before…​

```
<bean id="simple" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

After…​

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="simple" jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataSource">
</jee:jndi-lookup>
```

Now to convert this into a java config you will need to do something like this:

```
@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean simple() {
   JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
   bean.setJndiName("jdbc/MyDataSource");
   return bean;
}
```

Then you can just retrieve the jndi object from the bean.

References:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee-jndi-lookup-environment-single

Disclaimer: The public void afterPropertiesSet() must run to populate the jndi object.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be: Who is running the JNDI service that will give the data source to my app?

If your app doesn't run on a Java EE app server with a JNDI service available, the answer is "No one."  You should use a `DriverManager` data source in that case.

If your app does run on a Java EE app server with a JNDI service available, you have to know how to set up your data source in the pool.